# While implementing the MVC architecture how to notify the View class that the model has finally received the data from a call to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to implement the MVC architecture in a simple firebase login.

the user will insert the email and password in the view then the view will call the controller

This is the snippet of the view code (LoginView):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view==buttonLogin){
            LoginResult(editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim(),editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());
        }

    @Override
    public void LoginResult(String email , String password) {
        message = loginController.getInformedLogin(email , password);
        Toast.makeText(this, message ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

This is the snippet of the controller code (LoginController):

```
    @Override
    public void getInformedLogin(String email, String password) {
        userm = new UserModel(email , password);
        userm.LoginStatus();
    }
```

This is the snippet of the model code (User):

```
    @Override
    public void LoginStatus() {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(this.email)){
            //email is empty
            ResultMessage= "Please enter an email";
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            //password is empty
            ResultMessage = "Please enter a password";
        }


        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(UserModel.this ,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
                                ResultMessage= "Login successful";
                            }else{
                                ResultMessage="You need to verify your email first";
                            }
                        }else{
                            ResultMessage=task.getException().getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                });


    }
```

When debugging I know that the app process reaches the Model and enters the LoginStatus function my main problem is I do not know what to do when i get the task from firebase.

for example let's say task.successful is true. What do i do next? in order to notify the view class

I tried to make an intent but it did not work 
I also tried to pass a reference of the view class to the constructor of the model and then put the view class in the setoncompletelistener.But I guess there is something I am missing here it didn't work.

Maybe this is not the right way to do it I am open to any suggestion

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you try using callback ?

Comment: Use live data https://medium.com/@taman.neupane/basic-example-of-livedata-and-viewmodel-14d5af922d0  . treat viewmodel as your controller in MVC

Answer (score 0):

There's no necessity to create a new instance of your OnCompleteListener each time you call loginStatus method. It could be a variable in your controller and inject it as a parameter of loginStatus. That way you'd resole your problem.

Anyway i'd suggest you to go a bit deeper into architecture and begin with basic examples of Clean Arch.

[image]